# Smart tool (addin?) for creating class body from header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, header

you probably know this -- you're going to create some nice class, you think about it a little, maybe even draw a little UML here and there and then you're ready for implementation. You create header files with member functions, maybe even some member properties.

And now comes the dull work -- rewriting everything into .cpp file. It's true using stuff like Visual Assist can shorter this task but still -- do I really need to do this? Is there any tool / addin / direct functionality in Visual Studio which does this for me? You know, something like right click on header file in Solution explorer, "Create new .cpp for this header file".

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, Rational Rose could generate (and round trip) C++ code.

[IBM Rational](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/?S_TACT=105AGY59&S_CMP=13&ca=dtl-13)http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/?S_TACT=105AGY59&S_CMP=13&ca=dtl-13

Answer (score 1):

ArgoUML is a program we use at work to do class diagrams, which lets you easily view the .h and .cpp files of the classes you build.  Not just in C++, but also in PHP(4/5), C#, and Java.  It doesn't let you make diagrams from .h files, so I don't know if it would be particularly useful to you if you already have your headers written.  For the future, though, it could help.

Answer (score 0):

No.

But I agree that it would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

DevExtra http://www.toptensoftware.com/devextra/